# How to apply drag and drop for a div spanning multiple cells

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on a side project to recreate diablo / tarkov like inventory screens with pure html, css, and js. I'm attempting to use the draggable api's built into html for this but am hitting a blocker. Everything working fine for 1x1 wide/high cell's / items. The problem begins when trying to add an item that is longer in width and/or height. I can still drag around the item but I can't get it to do two things.

1. Cover all the cells correctly so there is no bleed through from the cells background.
2. Stop the item from being placed in a cell that would cover another item.

My ideal solution modifies either the linked codepen below or provides direction / a solution on a more appropriate approach whatever that may be. The only constraint is that it must use html, css, and javascript. The only exception is jQuery.

## The Code

```js
var draggedItem = null;

function Inventory(options) {
    // Setup Rows and Items
    this.init = function (options) {
        let slotSizeW = options.size.w / options.slots.w;
        let slotSizeH = options.size.h / options.slots.h;

        this.html = { inventory: options.selector };

        // Build grid
        let grid = document.createElement("grid");
        grid.style.width = options.size.w + "px";
        grid.style.height = options.size.h + "px";
        grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = "1fr ".repeat(options.slots.w);
        grid.style.gridTemplateRows = "1fr".repeat(options.slots.h);
        grid.cells = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < options.slots.w * options.slots.h; i++) {
            var cell = document.createElement("cell");
            cell.style.width = slotSizeW + "px";
            cell.style.height = slotSizeH + "px";
            grid.appendChild(cell);
            grid.cells.push(cell);
        }
        this.html.grid = grid;
        this.html.inventory.appendChild(this.html.grid);

        // Add all items
        let items = [];
        options.items.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
            items.push(item);
            let itemEl = document.createElement("item");
            itemEl.setAttribute("draggable", true);
            itemEl.style.background = item.color;
            itemEl.style.width = 100 * item.w + "%";
            itemEl.style.height = 100 * item.h + "%";

            grid.cells[options.slots.w * item.x + item.y].appendChild(itemEl);
        });
        this.html.items = items;

        let itemTags = document.querySelectorAll("item");
        for (let i = 0; i < itemTags.length; i++) {
            itemTags[i].addEventListener("dragstart", this.dragStart);
            itemTags[i].addEventListener("dragend", this.dragEnd);
        }

        let cellTags = document.querySelectorAll("cell");
        for (let i = 0; i < cellTags.length; i++) {
            cellTags[i].addEventListener("dragover", this.dragOver);
            cellTags[i].addEventListener("dragenter", this.dragEnter);
            cellTags[i].addEventListener("dragleave", this.dragLeave);
            cellTags[i].addEventListener("drop", this.dragDrop);
        }
    };

    this.dragStart = function () {
        this.classList.toggle("hold");
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.classList.toggle("invisible"));
        draggedItem = this;
    };
    this.dragEnd = function () {
        this.classList.toggle("hold");
        this.classList.toggle("invisible");
    };

    this.dragOver = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };
    this.dragEnter = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.classList.toggle("hovered");
    };
    this.dragLeave = function (e) {
        this.classList.remove("hovered");
    };
    this.dragDrop = function (e) {
        this.classList.remove("hovered");
        if (draggedItem != null) {
            draggedItem.parentElement.removeChild(draggedItem);
            this.appendChild(draggedItem);
        }
    };

    this.init(options);
}

var inventory = new Inventory({
    selector: document.querySelector("inventory"),
    size: { w: 300, h: 300 },
    slots: { w: 4, h: 4 },
    items: [
        { x: 0, y: 0, w: 2, h: 2, content: "2x2", color: "#ffd54f" },
        { x: 2, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2, content: "1x2", color: "#66bb6a" },
        { x: 3, y: 3, w: 1, h: 1, content: "1x1", color: "#e53935" }
    ]
});
```

```css
html,
body {
    background: darksalmon;
}

grid {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
}

cell {
    position: relative;
    border: 3px salmon solid;
    background-color: white;
}

item {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
}

.hold {
    border: solid #ccc 4px;
}

.hovered {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border-style: dashed;
}

.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<container>
    <inventory>
    </inventory>
</container>
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if the user tries to drag an item into a position where it would overlap another item? Does it just go back to its pre-drag position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get each item's color to fill the underlying cells you have to take into account the extra width of each cell created by its border.

This snippet sets the width and height of an item using this formula:

```
    itemEl.style.width = "calc((100% + 6px) * " + item.w + " - 4.9px)";
    itemEl.style.height =  "calc((100% + 6px) * " + item.h + " - 4.9px)";
```

This says add on an allowance for all 4 borders but remove the width of the outer borders. However, there can be a 'quirk' where the calculation the system has to do to map CSS pixels to screen pixels (several screen pixels may be used for one CSS pixel in modern displays) results in the odd screen pixel being left behind - in this case resulting in a thin white line around the item's color.

The item is made slightly wider (by just over 1 CSS pixel) and is placed half a pixel up and left which, at least in the tests I did with Edge/Chrome Windows10 removed this white 'border' at all zoom levels.

```js
var draggedItem = null;

function Inventory(options) {
    // Setup Rows and Items
    this.init = function (options) {
        let slotSizeW = options.size.w / options.slots.w;
        let slotSizeH = options.size.h / options.slots.h;

        this.html = { inventory: options.selector };

        // Build grid
        let grid = document.createElement("grid");
        grid.style.width = options.size.w + "px";
        grid.style.height = options.size.h + "px";
        grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = "1fr ".repeat(options.slots.w);
        grid.style.gridTemplateRows = "1fr".repeat(options.slots.h);
        grid.cells = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < options.slots.w * options.slots.h; i++) {
            var cell = document.createElement("cell");
            cell.style.width = slotSizeW + "px";
            cell.style.height = slotSizeH + "px";
            grid.appendChild(cell);
            grid.cells.push(cell);
        }
        this.html.grid = grid;
        this.html.inventory.appendChild(this.html.grid);

        // Add all items
        let items = [];
        options.items.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
            items.push(item);
            let itemEl = document.createElement("item");
            itemEl.setAttribute("draggable", true);
            itemEl.style.background = item.color;
            //itemEl.style.width = 100 * item.w + "%";
            //itemEl.style.height = 100 * item.h + "%";
           
            itemEl.style.width = "calc((100% + 6px) * " + item.w + " - 4.9px)";
            itemEl.style.height =  "calc((100% + 6px) * " + item.h + " - 4.9px)";

            grid.cells[options.slots.w * item.x + item.y].appendChild(itemEl);
        });
        this.html.items = items;

        let itemTags = document.querySelectorAll("item");
        for (let i = 0; i < itemTags.length; i++) {
            itemTags[i].addEventListener("dragstart", this.dragStart);
            itemTags[i].addEventListener("dragend", this.dragEnd);
        }

        let cellTags = document.querySelectorAll("cell");
        for (let i = 0; i < cellTags.length; i++) {
            cellTags[i].addEventListener("dragover", this.dragOver);
            cellTags[i].addEventListener("dragenter", this.dragEnter);
            cellTags[i].addEventListener("dragleave", this.dragLeave);
            cellTags[i].addEventListener("drop", this.dragDrop);
        }
    };

    this.dragStart = function () {
        this.classList.toggle("hold");
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.classList.toggle("invisible"));
        draggedItem = this;
    };
    this.dragEnd = function () {
        this.classList.toggle("hold");
        this.classList.toggle("invisible");
    };

    this.dragOver = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };
    this.dragEnter = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.classList.toggle("hovered");
    };
    this.dragLeave = function (e) {
        this.classList.remove("hovered");
    };
    this.dragDrop = function (e) {
        this.classList.remove("hovered");
        if (draggedItem != null) {
            draggedItem.parentElement.removeChild(draggedItem);
            this.appendChild(draggedItem);
        }
    };

    this.init(options);
}

var inventory = new Inventory({
    selector: document.querySelector("inventory"),
    size: { w: 300, h: 300 },
    slots: { w: 4, h: 4 },
    items: [
        { x: 0, y: 0, w: 2, h: 2, content: "2x2", color: "#ffd54f" },
        { x: 2, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2, content: "1x2", color: "#66bb6a" },
        { x: 3, y: 3, w: 1, h: 1, content: "1x1", color: "#e53935" }
    ]
});
```

```css
html,
body {
    background: darksalmon;
}

grid {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
}

cell {
    position: relative;
    border: 3px salmon solid;
    background-color: white;
}

item {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -0.5px;
    left: -0.5px;
}

.hold {
    border: solid #ccc 4px;
}

.hovered {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border-style: dashed;
}

.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<container>
    <inventory>
    </inventory>
</container>
```

For the second part of the question on a drop you will have to loop through the items to see if any overlaps with the dragged item and if it doesn't then you can remove the dragged item from its current cell and append it to its new one.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!